# How to edit datepicker format from dd/mm/yyyy to dd.mm.yyyy 00:00:00

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-ui-datepicker

I would like to use datepicker to insert date and time into textbox.

i need to change `dd/mm/yyyy` to `dd.mm.yyyy 00:00:00` using jquery

mine is here:

```
$(function() {
$("#TextBoxStart").datepicker({ altFormat: "dd.mm.yy" });
});


$(function() {
$("#TextBoxStop").datepicker({ altFormat: "dd.mm.yy" });

});
```

but doesnt work as i said

thanks all interest

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish, but wouldn't the `dateFormat` property achieve what you're after?

Comment: I think he want's date and TIME, download this and try: http://plugins.jquery.com/datetimepicker/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use date time picker instead of using only datepicker

```
$('.datetimepicker')
    .datetimepicker({ 
        dateFormat: 'yy.mm.dd', 
        timeFormat: 'HH:mm' 
     });
```

[Adding a Timepicker to jQuery UI Datepicker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/)

Answer (score 1):

Use DateTimePicker:

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
  format:'d.m.Y H:i',
});
```

output like this :
04.02.2014 11:18

Check it : http://jsfiddle.net/mehmetakifalp/v6CZv/

and more : http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/